# ModuleNotFoundError - Python Module Organization

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

I am trying to create a python module named `some_module` by putting the source code under the `src/` directory and tests under the `tests/` directory.

Current `tree` structure looks like this from `some_module/` directory

```
└─[$] <git:(property_play*)> tree
.
├── __init__.py
├── src
│   ├── birds.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── mammals.py
│   └── __pycache__
│       ├── birds.cpython-36.pyc
│       └── mammals.cpython-36.pyc
└── tests
    └── import_test.py

3 directories, 7 files
```

As we can see `src/` contains two python file named `birds.py` and `mammals.py`

Contents of `birds.py` are

```
class Birds:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Constructor for this class. '''
        # Create some member animals
        self.members = ['Sparrow', 'Robin', 'Duck']


        def printMembers(self):
        print('Printing members of the Birds class')
        for member in self.members:
           print('\t%s ' % member)
```

Contents of `mammals.py` are

```
class Mammals:
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Constructor for this class. '''
        # Create some member animals
        self.members = ['Tiger', 'Elephant', 'Wild Cat']


    def printMembers(self):
        print('Printing members of the Mammals class')
        for member in self.members:
            print('\t%s ' % member)
```

And finally the contents of `import_test.py`

```
from some_module.src.birds import Birds
from some_module.src.mammals import Mammals

# Create an object of Mammals class & call a method of it
myMammal = Mammals()
myMammal.printMembers()

# Create an object of Birds class & call a method of it
myBird = Birds()
myBird.printMembers()
```

Now, whenever I try to run the `import_test.py` I get the following error

```
└─[$] <git:(property_play*)> python3 import_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_test.py", line 5, in <module>
    from some_module.src.birds import Birds
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some_module'
```

I tried both relative, as well as absolute, importing but no luck. Can anyone please tell what am I missing here?

It will be really great if someone suggests the way to import these modules in a way such that command triggered `dir` has no impact on the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wanted to use absolute `import` paths instead of relative so that command triggered `dir` should not have an impact on these imports.

Building and installing my module is the way to go. I added one small `setup.py` using `setuptools` to solve my problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re

from setuptools import setup


def find_packages(package):
    """
    Return root package and all sub-packages.
    """
    return [
        dirpath
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(package)
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(dirpath, "__init__.py"))
    ]


setup(
    name="some_module",
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Shravan Kumar Gond",
    description="Module For absolute imports",
    packages=find_packages("some_module"),
    include_package_data=True,
    cmdclass={
        "package": Package
    }
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Now, you can `build` and `install` your module in the `sys.path` by running the following commands

```
$ python3 setup.py build
$ python3 setup.py install
```

Now all the absolute `import` should work like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

The organization in your module is non-standard python. To get the code working in your case you would probably have to change:

```py
from some_module.src.birds import Birds
from some_module.src.mammals import Mammals
```

To

```py
from src.birds import Birds
from src.mammals import Mammals
```

But, depending on which folder you are trying to run your test from, you will likely need to check or modify the contents of `sys.path`.

You could also set your `$PYTHONPATH` to point to the root directory i.e. the `some_module` directory.

Overall though, I would suggest you read through [Python's import docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) to get an understanding of how imports work. Or just look at a modern project like [Starlette](https://github.com/encode/starlette) or use a complete tool for managing everything like [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/)